# Regular expression to get sass imports

Tags: javascript, sass

Hi guys can you provide me regular expression to get sass and scss style @imports.

I have tried

```
/@import[\s"']*([^"';\n]+)[;"']*/g
```

But it is giving me only the first @import of list

```
@import "mainstyle",
"header",
"typography",
"somethingelese.scss";
```

It is giving me just `mainstyle` not the other ones. Please help.

Here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/subash/pen/koCvm) on codepen.

Comment: Updated the question to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass implements this logic already, so rather than write your own, you can do this using the Sass API like so:

```
ruby -rubygems -e "require 'sass/plugin'; puts Sass::Plugin::StalenessChecker.new(Sass::Plugin.engine_options).send(:dependencies, 'my_filename.sass', Sass::Importers::Filesystem.new('.')).map(&:first).join(%Q{\n})"
```

If you're using compass you would change that to this:

```
ruby -rubygems -e "require 'sass/plugin'; require 'compass'; puts Sass::Plugin::StalenessChecker.new(Compass.sass_engine_options).send(:dependencies, 'my_filename.sass', Sass::Importers::Filesystem.new('.')).map(&:first).join(%Q{\n})"
```

Answer (score 2):

It starts with `@import` and finishes with a semicolon, so:

```
/@import[^;]*;/gm
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/xewiwikeni/edit?js,console)